# Internal nested while loop wont execute

Tags: c++, opengl, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a nested while-loop structure, which will create a 3 * 3 grid of cubes. It only appears to run the internal loop one time, creating an "L" shape out of cubes. So, my guess is that the internal while loop is not resetting after it runs the first time, but I do appear to be explicitly resetting it.

I'd rather not post the entire code, as some is code given by my TA, and it feels wrong to post that without their permission.

```
void display()
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

   UpdateTransform();

   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   float Xres = 0;
   float Yres = 0;
   while(x < 3)
   {
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(Xres,0,0);
     drawOneCube();
     glPopMatrix();

     Xres += 0.3;


     while(y < 3)
     {

       glPushMatrix();
       glTranslatef(0,Yres,0);
       drawOneCube();
       glPopMatrix();


       Yres += 0.3;
       y++;
     }

     y = 0;
     Yres = 0;
     x++;
   }

   glutSwapBuffers();//this prevents that problem where the window copies the contents behind the window, possibly with glClear at the top of this function
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your logic is incorrect. You should only be calling the cube drawing function at one point, something like this:

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    UpdateTransform();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    float Xres = 0;
    float Yres = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
    {
        Yres = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(Xres,Yres,0);
            drawOneCube();
            glPopMatrix();
            Yres += 0.3;
        }
        Xres += 0.3;
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I still get the same "L" output.

Comment: What difference does it make to the loop? The variable `y` is set to zero already and is reset. The OPs problem is unlikely to have anything with the loop not executing.

Comment: @mock: either he added that or I missed it. (I'm quite sure he added it due to my response.)

Comment: (Well, stackoverflow is interesting! This is my first post, wasn't expecting such fast responses! And Chad just cleaned up my code I believe, added indentation to make it prettier and more readable. My bad :D) but, still attempting to figure this out, for loop didn't solve it for me, but trying all suggestions.

Comment: You're brilliant, thanks that works perfect. Yeah, my logic was totally flawed, but I see why now. Thank you! :D

Comment: If I was brilliant I would've noticed it in the first place. :-)